# Registering DCOM proxy on client machine

Tags: com, proxy, dcom

I have a .net 2 COM+ class library. It is installed on my machine running as the host server.

The COM+ object builds and registers, and I am able to call if via VB (open Excel and using dev mode added the reference, and then can call the object without any problems).

Now attempting to deploy to our test machine. Tried the following:

Export the COM+ object as Application Proxy

Export the COM+ object as Application Proxy with "Save application in COM+ 1.0 format."

After taking the msi and cab files to the client machine, ran the MSI. There were no errors on installation.

The object does show up in the registry (searched for it by GUID). The object does NOT however show up in the DCOM Config tree (also checked the COM+ tree as well just to make sure it is not there).

Looking at the win32 file in registry for the object, it shows it pointing to c:\Program Files\COMPlus Applications\ {GUID} \class.tlb   This is valid as that is where the tlb is sitting, and the GUIDs match as well.

Does anyone know how to get this to work correctly?

Additional information:
The COM+ object is built via ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual as AutoDispose and None I could not get to work correctly.